# Why my custom style are not applied in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have searching a lot a method to customize the Action Bar.

Basically I need to give color, text color to the action bar and color, text color, underline color to the navigation tabs of the action bar (they are under action bar).

So I have prepared a XML style file that is the following. You can see that in the second block there are all the reference to the text styles and navigation tabs styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles: inherit the parent theme and override it with other themes -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#6b3f8f</item> <!-- #5b327c  -->
    <!-- <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item> -->
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/tabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<!-- navigations tabs styles -->
<style name="tabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The color of the ActionBar is changing but not the others, why? I think to have extended the properties well. This is  my manifest:

```
<!-- @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light -->
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.ActionBar"
    android:allowBackup="true">
.....
</aplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:backgroundStacked` and `android:backgroundSplit` should be placed under `MyActionBar`, not your tab style because they're both inherit of `Widget.Holo.ActionBar`.

Comment: Thank you, now i can see the background color of tabs :)
Do you know which item extend to customize the text color of the tabs, the text of the main ActionBar and the underline color of the tabs? As you can see from my XML i have some styles but seems like i'm pointing to wrong items.

Comment: I solved myself the other style issues, you give me the first right way so i can accept your answer.